Higher confidence in Association Rule Mining
I’m trying to apply association rules mining on my dataset that has account id and merchant category codes(mcc). The aim is to identify the mcc codes where each customer frequently shops at irrespective of the transaction date. I’m using SAS/Proc SQL to create the rules and using the code below based on the association rule:
proc sql;
create table mcc_pairs as
select a.acct_id, a.mcc as mcc1, b.mcc as mcc2
from dfsample a inner join dfsample b
on a.acct_id=b.acct_id
where a.mcc^=b.mcc;
run;

proc freq data=mcc_pairs noprint;
tables acct_id*mcc1*mcc2/out=mcc_pair_counts(drop=percent);
run;

proc freq data=dfsample noprint;
tables acct_id*mcc/out=mcc_support(drop=percent);
run;

proc sql;
create table assoc_rules as
select a.acct_id, a.mcc1, a.mcc2, a.count as pair_count, b.count as mcc1_count, (a.count/b.count) as confidence format=percent8.2
from mcc_pair_counts as a inner join mcc_support as b
on a.acct_id=b.acct_id
order by confidence desc;
run;

However, my issue is that there are multiple pairs within each account id whose confidence are >100%. How should I interpret these values? Shouldn’t the confidence be <=100%? Is there something incorrect in the query?
I'm providing a sample dataset for reference:
data dfsample;
input acct_id mcc $;
datalines;
1 5411
1 5411
1 5812
1 5942
1 5942
2 5411
2 5812
2 5812
2 5967
2 5411
;
run;

With the above dataset, the confidence for many pairs are above 100%.

Please describe the rules you are trying to implement.  Does the order of the values in MCC1 and MCC2 matter? If not then you will have the same pairing represented twice in your first step.

@Tom Rules:

Identify MCC Pairs for Each Account: For each account_id, we want to see which MCCs frequently appear together across their transactions.
Count the Occurrences of Each Pair: For each pair of MCCs (mcc1, mcc2), we count how many times both MCCs were included in separate transactions for the same account. We use each occurrence of mcc1 in a transaction as an opportunity to pair with each occurrence of mcc2 for that account.
In this approach, order does not matter between mcc1 and mcc2. The pairs (5411, 5812) and (5812, 5411) would be considered the same in my analysis.


How do you define "appear together" when your source data has only one MCC variable?  Do you mean by appear together that they both are associated to the same ID?  You need to explain more clearly what you are counting.  You example is small enough you should be able to manually count and show the expected values for the given input.
